# Why is my customized toolbar not being saved when I restart Safari?

Tags: mac, safari

On Mac OS X Leopard 10.5.8, in Safari 4.0.3.

When I customize the toolbar there are no problems, but when Safari is restarted all changes are lost.

Customize toolbar:

[image]

Restart (quit then open) Safari, the toolbar goes back to the previous configuration:

[image]

Any ideas?  I have another Mac (10.5.8) that I was able to duplicate the problem on.

Comment: Maybe it's the Evernote plugin you use.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is a well known issue with Evernote's Safari Clipper.  The Evernote folks have fixed it once, but the fix actually cause the Evernote Safari Clipper plugin to overwrite other changes in the Toolbar.

The best solution at this point, is to Go into Evernote and turn off the Safari Clipper, and use the MenuBar Clipper instead.

Comment: That did the trick. In the Evernote desktop application go to Preferences, Clipping, then uncheck the box that says 'Use the Safari clipper plugin'

Answer (score 0):

It's just a guess, but your Safari preference list is probably read-only or corrupted. The plist is the file that stores general Safari settings, and I suggest you might want to make a backup of your current plist, and then delete it, and restart Safari again.

The plist can be found at

> ***your home directory***\Library\Preferences\com.apple.Safari.plist

So again :

1. Quit Safari
2. Backup com.apple.Safari.plist
3. Delete com.apple.Safari.plist
4. Restart Safari

**EDIT**
If the problem could be duplicated on both Macs, it might be a plug-in that is causing the problem. Disable all plug-ins and re-enable them one by one to see if any is causing this symptom.

**EDIT EDIT**
Found a [thread](http://discussions.apple.com/thread.jspa?messageID=10060639) on the same problem you have. Apparently it *is* one of the input managers (plug-ins) causing this symptom - in particular TabExpose.